# Proxy get handler called on evaluation of proxy

Tags: javascript, node.js, proxy

I defined a proxy as follows:

```
const o1 = {
      ready: false
    };

setTimeout(() => {
  o1.ready = true;
}, 1000000000);

const handler = {
  get(target, propKey, receiver) {
    if (target.ready == false) {
      throw new Error('not ready');
    } else {
      return 'ready'
    }
  }
};

const proxy = new Proxy(o1, handler);

proxy; // raises 'not ready'
```

Evaluating `proxy` raises the error 'not ready', even though it isnt a property access. How do I prevent the error from being raised when the reference to the proxy is evaluated? This causes bugs when requiring without assignment.

Comment: What environment are you seeing this? Testing on chrome and it works as expected, edit: just reproduced in node

Comment: node v8.7.0. no error for me on chrome as well :/

Comment: created an issue on github, will update with details

Comment: hmmmm... i dont get either `ready` or `not ready`. the get handler of a proxy is meant for accessing properties on the proxy itself. `proxy.ready` would trigger `not ready`. but, i cant see how your code could be triggering anything....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be related to this bug: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/10731

The best work around I've found is to specifically ignore the node inspection:

```
const handler = {
  get(target, propKey, receiver) {
    if (propKey != util.inspect.custom && 
        propKey != 'inspect' && 
        propKey != Symbol.toStringTag){
      if (target.ready == false) {
        throw new Error('not ready');
      } else {
        return 'ready'
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Or alternatively if you knew the list of keys you cared about then just check those instead of excluding.

Comment: It looking for 'inspect' is the odd part :/. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you're evaluating this in the REPL, where the final `proxy;` statement makes for the result value of the code and which is logged to the console. Logging it will access the properties, that's expected.

However, you really should not be using a proxy here. A proxy should handle different properties individually, but yours appears to only care about the `ready` property. A simpler getter would be more appropriate:

```
const o1 = {
  ready: false
};
setTimeout(() => {
  o1.ready = true;
}, 1000000000);

const res = { // instead of the `proxy` object
  get ready() {
    if (o1.ready == false) {
      throw new Error('not ready');
    } else {
      return 'ready'
    }
  }
};

res.ready // either throws or yields the string "ready"
```